# Set Map to Show My Position not in Centre

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I am using `com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap` in an application I am trying out. Map view shows my position in centre but I want to always show my position slightly below centre so that more space is visible on the map for the path ahead.

Documentation says that I can get the actual space covered by my view by using `getProjection()` and use a custom value in `moveCamera()` after doing some calculation (by feeding a calculated value rather than feeding my actual location) but the documentation also sates that `getProjection()` is expensive and therefore I should not use it more than once.

Is there a more appropriate way to achieve this(Kind of defining a custom centre in the view maybe)?

Comment: You can try to set the padding of the map or do the `latlng` change to the `CameraUpdateFactory`:https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory within it you can update `CameraPosition`
`CameraPosition(LatLng target, float zoom, float tilt, float bearing)`, add the value to the `LatLng target` to make your camera not in the center.

Comment: @bjiang Yes, but in order to do that I need to know how much horizontal area is covered by the view so that I can calculate the latlng accordingly. But the function get how much of area is covered by the view ('getProjection()') is expensive. But the map updates every second or so. Anyway I'll try this out. Thanks!